# Showing data in a list view JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code. At this moment only one product display. I would like to display all of the products by the click of a button or on page load.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Products
    </title>

    <script src="/appmachine/core.js"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bridge/core.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> window.App</script>

</head>

<body>

    <p id="name"></p> 
    <p id="imageid"></p>
     <p id="shop"></p>
     <p id="description"></p>

    <a onClick="window.App.navigateToBlock('products', function(alert('Succes')))">Test</a>

</body>

 <script>

App.getCurrentRecord(function(products){
document.getElementById('name' ).innerHTML = products.name; 
document.getElementById('imageid').innerHTML = '<img width="300" src="'+ products.imageid +'"/>'; 
document.getElementById('shop').innerHTML = products.shop; 
document.getElementById('description').innerText = products.description; 
});

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You should probably put it in an unorder list and dynamically create list items with all the product detail as you iterate over your products array. Not sure what you're looking for, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual DOM manipulation is painful, try using templates.

This example uses [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/), but you can use whatever you prefer.

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/joyopuruku/edit?html,js,output)**

```
<div id="target"></div>

<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
  {{#products}}
  <p id="name">{{ name }}</p> 
  <img id="imageid" src="{{imageid}} />
  <p id="shop">{{ shop }}</p>
  <p id="description">{{ description }}</p>
  {{/products}}
</script>
```

The syntax `{{#products}} {{/products}}` specifies a list based off of JSON data.

```
var products = {
  "products": [{
    name: "Alice",
    imageid: '<img width="300" src="#"/>',
    shop: 'Test Shop',
    description: 'test description'
  }, {
    name: "Bob",
    imageid: '<img width="300" src="#"/>',
    shop: 'Another Shop',
    description: 'super description'
  }]
};
```

Using this data you can populate the template in JavaScript.

```
function loadView(products) {
  var template = $('#template').html();
  Mustache.parse(template);

  var rendered = Mustache.render(template, products);
  $('#target').html(rendered);
}

loadView(products);
```